# Is there a way to efficiently find all unique values for a field in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

Consider a collection of Users:

```
{ name: 'Jeff' }
{ name: 'Joel' }
```

Is there a way to efficiently get all the unique values for `name`?

```
User.pluck(:name).uniq
```

To return

```
[ 'Jeff', 'Joel' ]
```

I think this would get the whole collection, so it would be inefficient.

However, if there is an index on `name`, is there a way to get all the unique values without getting all the documents?

Or is there another way to efficiently get the unique `names`?

Comment: use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Comment: @Yogesh - That would work, but the documentation does not show how efficient it is.

Comment: ["When possible, `db.collection.distinct()` operations can use indexes"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#index-use) so (1) it is happening inside the database and (2) if you have an index, it will pull the list straight out of the index. `pluck` gives you an array and then `Array#uniq` is used, this is almost certainly going to be a lot slower than letting the database do the work.

Comment: @Yogesh: note that if `distinct` finds more data than fits into doc size limit, the operation will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can efficiently get the unique values of a field over all docs in a collection using [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

The documentation specifically mentions that indexes are used when possible, and that they can cover the distinct query. This means that only the supporting index needs to be loaded into memory to get the results.

> When possible, `db.collection.distinct()` operations can use indexes.
>
> Indexes can also [cover](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-queries) `db.collection.distinct()` operations. See
>   [Covered Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-queries) for more information on queries covered by indexes.

In Ruby, you would perform your distinct query as:

```
User.distinct(:name)
```